# Sound export in 44100 Hz instead of 48000 Hz, why?

Tags: export, video-sequence-editor, audio

I started to use Blender as a solution for video editing, very powerful and agreeable. Nevertheless, I have a bug that I can't resolve. The sound of my  video is in 48kHz, my users preferences are also in 48kHz, but when I export in H264 the final editing, the sound goes out in 44kHz.

I also exported the sound only in wav, and same issue. Any idea where this issue comes from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sound frequency for the project is set here:

[image]

change it to 48000 Hz.

Comment: i am such a newbie... thx you very much!